# What happens when you change the variable in differentiation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was asked a somewhat elementary question, but it got me a bit confused.

Suppose I have a function $f(k)$ and I change variables, so now $k = \frac{c}{y}$ where $c$ is constant. What happens to $\frac{df(k)}{dk}$ under this change?

Is this correct: $dk = -\frac{c}{y^2} dy$, so

$$\frac{df(k)}{dk} = \frac{df(\frac{c}{y})}{-\frac{c}{y^2} dy} =-\frac{y^2}{c} \frac{df(\frac{c}{y})}{dy}$$

Comment: It seemed very reasonable to me. What is your doubt about it?

Answer (score 1):

Simply apply the chain rule for your variable change: $k=c/y$
$$\frac{df(k)}{dk} = \frac{df(y(k))}{dy}\frac{dy}{dk} =-\frac{c}{k^2} \frac{df}{dy}=-\frac{y^2}{c} \frac{df}{dy}$$